# Clickable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, oauth

I'm using the @anywhere Twitter login to connect to my app. It is a JavaScript function and when you click it, it authorizes and then brings the user to the profile page. I'm using the [Tutorial here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#login-signup) for the button. I'm not even sure how it could be clickable. This is the code that I have in place:

```
<span id="login"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">



  twttr.anywhere(function (T) {

    T("#login").connectButton({ 

      authComplete: function(user) {

        // triggered when auth completed successfully

      },

      signOut: function() {

        // triggered when user logs out

      }

    });

  });


</script>
```

I was thinking of an `<a href="foo" </a>` for it but I don't know how it would work. Thanks!

Comment: Are you wondering how the button appears there? It's all inside the twitter javascript framework. The .connectButton() function does all the DOM work and add's the button to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the twitter script in the header of the HTML:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=YOUR_API_KEY&v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Then it should work - Just make sure that the thing in T("#login") matches your id in the span.

Comment: That works, but when you click it, is it possible to bring you to another page? Like a link almost